# Dead keys are not working in custom XKB layout

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

I use a custom XKB layout derived from stock layout hr(us):

```
{
    name[Group1] = "My HR Layout";
    include "hr(us)"
    key <AB09> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol, dead_doublegrave, dead_invertedbreve ] }; // D˵ D? 
    key <AB10> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,     dead_acute,    dead_macron ] }; //   D´ 
    key <AC01> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,     adiaeresis,     Adiaeresis ] }; //   ä Ä 
    key <AC03> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,            eth                 ] }; //   ð 
    key <AC09> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,        lstroke,        Lstroke ] }; //   ł Ł 
    key <AD03> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,          U011B,          U011A ] }; //   ě Ě 
    key <AD07> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,     udiaeresis,     Udiaeresis ] }; //   ü Ü 
    key <AD08> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,     idiaeresis,     Idiaeresis ] }; //   ï Ï 
    key <AD09> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,     odiaeresis,     Odiaeresis ] }; //   ö Ö 
    key <AE01> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,    onesuperior                 ] }; //   ¹ 
    key <AE02> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,    twosuperior                 ] }; //   ² 
    key <AE03> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,  threesuperior                 ] }; //   ³ 
    key <AE04> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,          U2074,          U20AC ] }; //   ⁴ € 
    key <AE05> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,          U2075                 ] }; //   ⁵ 
    key <AE06> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,          U2076                 ] }; //   ⁶ 
    key <AE07> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,          U2077                 ] }; //   ⁷ 
    key <AE08> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,          U2078                 ] }; //   ⁸ 
    key <AE09> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,          U2079                 ] }; //   ⁹ 
    key <AE10> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,          U2070,          U00B0 ] }; //   ⁰ °
    key <AE11> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,         endash,         emdash ] }; //   – — 
    key <TLDE> { [       NoSymbol,       NoSymbol,     dead_grave                 ] }; //   D` 
};
```

Everything works fine except dead keys which behave differently:

- Dead grave (AltGr-TLDE), dead acute (AltGr-AB10) and dead macron (AltGr-Shift-AB10) work fine, and in combination with latin 'a' produce 'à', 'á' and 'ā' respectively.
- Dead double grave (AltGr-AB09) does not work. Pressing AltGr-AB09 followed by latin 'a' does not produce any symbol at all, although it should produce 'ȁ', which is definded under X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose:

```
<dead_doublegrave> <a>                      : "ȁ"   U0201 # LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DOUBLE GRAVE
```

- Dead inverted breve (AltGr-Shift-AB09) does not work also, but differently. Pressing AltGr-Shift-AB09 followed by latin 'a' produces just 'a' although it should produce 'ȃ' which is also defined under composition rules:

```
<dead_invertedbreve> <a>                    : "ȃ"   U0203 # LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH INVERTED BREVE
```

Searching for help on that issue, or at least an advice on how to even debug that XKB hell, where to start and what tools to use. I'm not a newbie in development and system administration but XKB always makes my head ache.